# Linuc Oracle 11g enable partitioning using chopt

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I ran the following query:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM v$option WHERE parameter = 'Partitioning'
```

And the result is:

```
false
```

On directory oracle/product/11.2.3/bin/, I'm trying to run this command to enable the partition option:

```
chopt enable partitioning
```

And the error occurs:

```
-bash: chopt: command not found
```

I'm not understanding why this command does not work, and on all the sites I've researched ask to do that way.

## EDIT

You need oracle enterprise edition to enable partitioning option

Comment: So have you actually paid for the Partitioning licence?

Answer (score 1):

chopt still needs the oracle environment set appropriately, eg

```
[oracle@db19 ~]$ chopt
bash: chopt: command not found

[oracle@db19 ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [db19] ? 
The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle

[oracle@db19 ~]$ chopt

usage:

chopt <enable|disable> <option>

options:
                 oaa = Oracle Advanced Analytics
                olap = Oracle OLAP
        partitioning = Oracle Partitioning
                 rat = Oracle Real Application Testing

e.g. chopt enable rat
```

Comment: The solution works. But when I enable the partitioning option then my database don't works anymore. Inside the enable_partitioning.log there is some commands, It's to remove oracle file and run gcc to generate new oracle file.